# Как посчитать количество повторений в RStudio?

Tags: dataframe, r, table, count, rstudio

Знаю, что посчитать повторения в таблице можно через table(x), но есть одна проблема: выводится это все, как одномерный массив, можно ли как-то сделать, чтоб количество выводилось отдельным столбцом в table? Или подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь любой другой способ для отображения количества повторений отдельным столбцом

Comment: привет. а есть хотя бы примерные данные? или вставь ```dput(data)```, где ```data``` - твой датафрейм

Answer (score 1):

```
x -> data.frame(table(your_df))
```

Получатся два столбца: x и Freq; x - наблюдение, Freq - его частота.